# Setkey on a numeric column

Tags: r, data.table

I'm experiencing an issue while setting a numeric key on a data table. I took the **mtcars** dataframe and converted it to a **data.table** as:

```
dt<- as.data.table(mtcars,keep.rownames=T)
```

I then set key for **dt** as a numeric column *cyl* as:

```
setkey(dt,cyl)
```

Now I simply wanted to subset **dt** where *cyl* is either 4 or 6. Trying to subset with the key concept I did the following:

```
dt[.(4,6)]
```

There is no error, however the output is contrary to what I wanted to do:

```
    cyl AM  mpg  disp  hp Drat    wt  qsec vs gear carb V2
 1:   4  1 22.8 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1    4    1  6
 2:   4  0 24.4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1    4    2  6
 3:   4  0 22.8 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1    4    2  6
 4:   4  1 32.4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1    4    1  6
 5:   4  1 30.4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1    4    2  6
 6:   4  1 33.9  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1    4    1  6
 7:   4  0 21.5 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1    3    1  6
 8:   4  1 27.3  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1    4    1  6
 9:   4  1 26.0 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0    5    2  6
10:   4  1 30.4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1    5    2  6
11:   4  1 21.4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1    4    2  6
```

So instead of getting a subset of rows where *cyl* is 4 or 6, I'm getting rows where *cyl* is 4 and then an unwanted column created having values 6. I'm a bit perplexed because I tried `dt[.(4)]` and `dt[.(6)]` and they worked fine. Just when I give more than one value for filtering(like 4,6 together in this case)is when it gives me this output. 
Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: You need to pass a *vector* of  values: `dt[.(c(4,6))]`.

Comment: That actually solved it !! I was doing dt[c(4,6)] and dt[.(4,6)]. Thanks for your kind help. Much appreciated.